# How to use LINQ to pass the cell value from DataGridView to ListBox

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, listbox

I want to pass the colored cell value to the `ListBox`. But unfortunately, I can't do this by using the following code.

What I have done wrong?

```
var cellColorValue = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .SelectMany(row => row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                    .Where(c => c.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
                    .Select(x => x.Value).ToString()
                    .ToList());
listBox1.Items.Add(cellColorValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you are trying to add items in the listbox but you are providing it an `List` of items. Which means, you cannot do it with simply calling the `Add()` method.

What you should do is, either pass the list `cellColorValue` into the `AddRange()` method or use a `DataSource` object to bind the values.

Do this:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(cellColorValue);
```

Or

```
listBox1.DataSource = cellColorValue;
listBox1.DataBind(); // Call this method as well to bind the data source.
```

**UPDATE**

I see, your resulting objects is an `EInumerable` of objects which the `AddRange()` method doesn't accept. I have refactored your LINQ expression as so it is sent to the `listbox` accordingly. Assuming that you want to get the cell values of the `DataGridView` in your listbox. See:

```
var cellColorValue = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                    .SelectMany(row => row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                    .Where(c => c.Style.BackColor == Color.Yellow)
                    .Select(cell => cell.Value.ToString()))
                    .ToArray();
```

And add that into the listbox like this:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(cellColorValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Jamshaid. I’ve tried, but neither the one nor the other works…

Comment: Conversion from "System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<objects>"to System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection" cannot be done

Comment: @Marcel16 Happy to help. Make sure to accept the answer if it helped. :)